# If two square of different area 25m2 and 36m2 are subjected to equal force 2N then which square will move with greater velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I think velocity has some relation with area

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer the question. (1) It isn't clear, but the implication is that there is an aerodynamics aspect to the problem (2) Area could mean frontal area or surface area (3) The relative mass of the bodies is undefined.

Comment: please do not respond to the closure of your question by re-posting it. Figure out what is wrong and edit the original to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is literally no relation whatsoever, assuming no air resistance or some other effect which I doubt you are asking about. Only the mass would determine the *acceleration* due to a given force. In this case, the object with great mass would be slower, assuming they started at rest.